# SASS if with or statement?

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to create an or statement in SASS?

Like this:

```
@if $color == "red" || "blue"
  width: 100%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
@if $color == red or blue
    width: 100%
```

Comment: I think color or any value should be without quotation marks :)